# How can i cast LinkedHashTreeMap to string type?

Tags: json, gson

JSON data

```
{
  "id": 8428514522228612,
  "name": "Order Acknowledgment",
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 7701511984703364,
      "index": 0,
      "title": "Order#",
      "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
      "primary": true
    }, {
      "id": 2072012450490244,
      "index": 1,
      "title": "Order Date",
      "type": "DATE"
    }
  ]
}
```

creating java object and able to getID value

```
MyJsonObject1 obj = gson.fromJson(line, MyJsonObject1.class);
System.out.println(obj.getId());
```

As columns is an Object array , i need to loop through it and get the columns key and pair values.
I need to get only the columns id,so i am trying the below code

```
    SingleMap nextActionInfoMap = new Gson().fromJson((String) col,SingleMap.class);
int column_id = nextActionInfoMap.getId();
System.out.println(column_id);


class MyJsonObject1 {

private String id;
private String name;
private Object[] columns;

public Object[] getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(JSONObject[] columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

```
public class SingleMap {

private int id;
private int index;
private String title;
private String type;
private String primary;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}
public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getPrimary() {
    return primary;
}
public void setPrimary(String primary) {
    this.primary = primary;
}
```

}

But i am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code of `MyJsonObject1` and `SingleMap`?

Comment: What is `col`? You're trying to cast that variable to a `String` and it seems it can't be done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the `columns` property in `MyJsonObject1` to be of type `SingleMap[]` or `List<SingleMap>` instead of `Object[]` then Gson should do all the parsing for you in one go, with no need to do a second pass to explicitly parse each column.

```
class MyJsonObject1 {

  private SingleMap[] columns;

  public SingleMap[] getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }

  public void setColumns(SingleMap[] columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
  }
//...
}
```